# replacing toilet wax ring seal frequency

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I just got a new home (used home). A handy guy I have that does work around the place told me that the wax seals under toilets need to be replaced periodically. I am looking around online about this and see people saying they only need to be replaced if there are any problems as opposed to just every X many years. Can anyone confirm all this one way or the other for me?

Comment: I only replace them if there is a leak. If the toilet is securely mounted and not moving it will last 20 years easily.

Comment: Is your "Handy Guy" looking for projects to fill his wallet?

Comment: What @EdBeal said: no toilet movement = perpetual life. Handy guy = suspicious.

Comment: first time homeowner here, so good to know!